# Not setting state in time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi people I'm still learning react and I have this function:

```
async function onSubmit(){
    try{
      const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${value.label}&key=${key}`;
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const results = await response.text();
      const data = await JSON.parse(results);
      setCounty(data.results[0].address_components[4].long_name.split(" ")[0])
      setAddress(data.results[0].formatted_address.split(",")[0]);
      setTown(data.results[0].formatted_address.split(", ")[1]);
      setZip(data.results[0].address_components[7].long_name);
      console.log('this is my county ' + county);
      upload()
    }catch(err){console.log(err)}
  }
```

Which isn't setting state in time for the next function call `upload()` which requires the states to be set since it makes another fetch using the states in the url. I did a little research and I though by using `async` `await` it would work but it's still not setting in time so I need help. How do I call `upload()` after the states have finished updating? Thank you for the help and if you have any feedback I'm very open to improving my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the state is happening **asynchronously**. You shouldn't expect variable `county` to be updated and presented in the given `console.log()`.

What you can do is either creating a separate variable and log out that as the following:

```
const countyValue = data.results[0].address_components[4].long_name.split(" ")[0]
setCounty(countyValue)
// ... rest of the state updates
console.log('this is my county ' + countyValue)
```

Or using `useEffect` hook to capture changes on `county` state as:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log('changed', county)
}, [county])
```

Be aware of using `useEffect` hook, you should add that code snippet into the **root** of your function component. It cannot be called within a function inside.

Suggested read is [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: woohoo thank you mister!! i mean this sort of worked but I'm now passing in the variables to my upload function like this upload(newcounty, newaddress, newtown, newzip) I guess i didn't need state at all 