# what happens in React hooks when executing some function after settingSomeState() function in parents function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

parent's clickHandler() function is called from its child, after executing setState() function What happens if on the next line is executed some other tasks ?

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("initial state");

  const clickHandler = (e) => {
    console.log("onclick", state);
    setState(e.target.innerText);
    console.log("onclick", state);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child clickHandler={clickHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}


function Child({ clickHandler }) {
  return (
    <div className="Child">
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am getting result `onclick initial state`  two times, but I suppose to get `onclick initial state` first and `onclick Click me`  second, or nothing at second time, why anyway it logs on secont time, does not setState supposed to cause rerender no matter what's next to execute in this function?

Comment: `setState` is happening asynchronously, that's why it's not updated there _**yet**_. I've explained a similar thing to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65942815/not-setting-state-in-time/65942866#65942866).

Answer (score 1):

`setState()` from `useState` is executed asynchronously. Once the state is actually set it will trigger a re-render. Your second `console.log` will not reliably have the accurate `state`.

If you want something else to happen after `state` has been set you can use a `useEffect` like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("State is:", state);
},[state]);
```

This will fire on load, and every time state is updated.